# RegEx Conditional Prefix & Suffix to Known-Length Internal Digits

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I have searched for answers to conditional prefixes, but I'm coming up blank. I anticipate I'm missing something simple, but I have been unsuccessful.

I am looking to match all of these series with a single regex line:

Here are the logic sections:

1. (Maybe 2 Letter Prefix, Maybe word boundary)
2. (seven digits)
3. (Maybe 2 character suffix [first always letter, second letter or
   number], maybe word boundary)

**Match Examples (letters and numbers are arbitrary):**

1234567

1234567B1

1234567A2

1234567AA

AA1234567

AA1234567A1

AA1234567

AA1234567BB

**Rejected:**

12345678

/1234567

-1234567

:1234567

01234567

AB12345678AB

---

**What I've tried:**

I keep trying to group there. Matching the seven consecutive digits is obviously simple '[0-9]{7}', but I am having difficulty matching caret NOT characters in optional groups.

For instance, if I do '[^\d]?[0-9]{7}' hoping to match a seven digit number that may have a prefix, but that prefix CANNOT be a digit, my matches without a prefix fails (i.e. just a seven digit string).

Clearly I'm new at regex, so any help is appreciated.

---

**EDIT** Thank you all! Each one of these seems to produce very close results to my actual test files, I'll have to test for a bit but for the time being it looks like we have multiple correct and efficient answers.

Comment: Are you trying to find these strings in the middle of a line or on their own on a line?

Comment: They can be anywhere - middle or their own.

Comment: Then could you provide more representative sample input and expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your request for a more representative output -- as I said, these alphanumeric strings are randomly scattered throughout a text file. No pattern whatsoever.

Comment: then simply show a small input file with the strings scattered throughout it and the output you'd want to get after running your desired tool on that file. I'm sure in your head you know exactly what you want, but it's IS ambiguous so it's hard for us to provide accurate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regex `^[a-zA-Z]{0,2}\d{7}([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d])?$`

```
^ string begin

[a-zA-Z]{0,2}Maybe 2 Letter Prefix, Maybe word boundary

\d{7} seven digits

([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d])?Maybe 2 character prefix [first always letter, second letter or number], maybe word boundary

$ string end
```

Comment: replace ^ and $ with \b (word boundary). otherwise "wordAA1234567B2word" can't be matched

Comment: \b[a-zA-Z]{0,2}\d{7}([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d])?\b matches /1234567
-1234567
:1234567

Comment: Use character classes instead of explicit character ranges as you don't know the OPs locale so, for example, [a-zA-Z] may not match the same characters as [[:alpha:]].

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the internal sections. It definitely helps me understand what's going on. I'll report back after some testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/^([[:alpha:]]{2})?[[:digit:]]{7}([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]])?$/' file
1234567
1234567B1
1234567A2
1234567AA
AA1234567
AA1234567A1
AA1234567
AA1234567BB
$ awk '!/^([[:alpha:]]{2})?[[:digit:]]{7}([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]])?$/' file
12345678
/1234567
-1234567
:1234567
01234567
AB12345678AB
```

Comment: I'd prefer not do do this in a two-step process. Is there a single line (without piping between the two above) I could use?

Comment: There is no pipe above. I showed 2 separate commands - one to print the lines that match the RE and one to print the lines that don't match the RE so you could compare tothe sample output you posted. Do you want both the selected and rejected lines printed? If so do you want that going to separate files or what? Do you want the whole lines output or just the matching strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lnE  'print if m{
        \A                        # Beginning of string
        (?:  [a-z]{2} | \b )?     # (Maybe 2 Letter Prefix, Maybe word boundary)
        \d{7}                     # (seven digits)
        (?: [a-z][a-z\d] | \b )?  # (Maybe 2 character suffix [first always letter, second letter or number], maybe word boundary)
        \z                        # End of string
    }xmsi' < file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/^([a-z]{2})?[0-9]{7}([a-z][a-z0-9])?$/Ip' file
```